# How to manage dropdown as link into mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi,
I am facing with some problems .In shopping cart link at header i used drop down,but when i changes the media size into responsive (mobile) so it should be simple hyperlink but it works as drop-down.This works according to bootstrap markup.

So can anyone tell me how to change the markup so in desktop media size it will works as drop-down  and in mobile device it should be like as link

here as mark-up for whole header links

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                @Html.Widget("header_links_before")
                @Html.Action("AdminHeaderLinks", "Common")
                @*<li>
                        @Html.Action("TaxTypeSelector", "Common")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.Action("CurrencySelector", "Common")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.Action("LanguageSelector", "Common")
                    </li>*@
                @if (Model.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerInfo")" class="account">@Model.CustomerEmailUsername</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Logout")" class="ico-logout">@T("Account.Logout")</a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Register")" class="ico-register">@T("Account.Register")</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Login")" class="ico-login">@T("Account.Login")</a></li>
                }
                @if (Model.AllowPrivateMessages)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("PrivateMessages", new { tab = "" })" class="ico-inbox">@T("PrivateMessages.Inbox")<span>@Model.UnreadPrivateMessages</span></a>
                    </li>
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.AlertMessage))
                    {
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                displayPopupNotification('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.AlertMessage))', 'success', false);
                            });
                        </script>
                    }
                }
                @if (Model.ShoppingCartEnabled)
                {
                    <li id="topcartlink" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ShoppingCart")" class="ico-cart dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="cart-label">@T("ShoppingCart")</span>
                            <span class="cart-qty">@T("ShoppingCart.HeaderQuantity", Model.ShoppingCartItems)</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                @Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart", "ShoppingCart")
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                }
                @if (Model.WishlistEnabled)
                {
                    <li>enter code here
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Wishlist")" class="ico-wishlist">`enter code here`
                            <span class="cart-label">@T("Wishlist")</span>
                            <span class="wishlist-qty">@T("Wishlist.HeaderQuantity", Model.WishlistItems)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
                @Html.Widget("header_links_after")
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please check the image link as below

http://imageupper.com/i/?S0200010090013K14096405471629783
http://imageupper.com/i/?S0200010090023K14096405471629783tw

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  $(this).siblings('.dropdown-backdrop').off().remove();
}
}, this), 0);
});
```

Comment: Also, another solution you can find here: http://www.jeffmould.com/2014/01/09/responsive-multi-level-bootstrap-menu/